# Async on different class with same Threadpool SpringBoot

Tags: spring-boot, spring-annotations, completable-future, threadpoolexecutor, spring-async

I have configured 1 threadpool @Async(value="pool_1"). now I want to use this threadpool in different classes, so I put @Async(value="pool_1") above my 2 different class. I just want to get confirmation like it won't create 2 seperate pool of thread.
Like I have set my pool size to 500 threads, putting same async on 2 different class, won't set pool size to 1000 right?
Also these threads will be **SHARED** and not be **divided** between 2 classes right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Like I have set my pool size to 500 threads, putting same async on 2 different class, won't set pool size to 1000 right?

All methods using `@Async(value="pool_1")` will use the same single thread pool (i.e. the one you configured with size 500).

> Also these threads will be SHARED and not be divided between 2 classes right

There is no upfront allocation of a fixed number of threads to each method (if that is what you asked for).